# Are there caching framework like SDWebImage or HJCache supporting ARC?

Tags: ios, hjcache

I found https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage and https://github.com/markofjohnson/HJCache
Both good approach for image async download and caching on disk and memory.
Is there something similar but supporting ARC?

Comment: Did you try MKNetworkKit? http://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit ARC based networking + caching framework.

Comment: That looks exactly what I needed, I'm using AFNEtworking and SDWebImage now, but both no ARC (not really a problem) but separated. SDWebImage doesn't seem to consider cache sizing and network indicator is messed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update: AFNetworking has added support to ARC. And for image caching, NSURLCache does disk caching since ios5, see here [here](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/nsurlcache-uses-a-disk-cache-as-of-ios5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use those libraries in an ARC project by setting the -fno-objc-arc flag on the class files from the library. See this answer for instructions:

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

ARC code can interoperate with ARC code without compromising the benefits to the code that your write yourself. ARC doesn't do anything magic except write your retain/release statements for you, so as long as SDWebImage doesn't have leaks, there's no benefit to converting it to ARC since the retain/release statements have already been written.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I do with AFNetworking, I was just hoping there was something new. Those frameworks are really good but I'd prefer SDK to take care of memory management.